# Android O Settings to enable background restriction for applications

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, notification-channel

As per the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#overview)-

> Note: By default, these restrictions only apply to apps that target
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable most
>   of these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if
>   the app targets an API level lower than 26.

I'm targeting Below API 26 but i cannot find the settings to enable the restriction in official android emulator.

Where is this setting available?

Comment: There are no restrictions in android versions below API 26

Comment: @user12345 i'm asking for app running at API 26, targeting below API 26.

Comment: Which android version is installed in emulator?

Comment: API 26= Android O

Comment: You might need to run on real device then.

Comment: probably they mean in Developer Options -> Background Processes -> No Background Processes instead of Standard Limit

Comment: @matrix that setting is different thing.

Comment: @user12345 post a screenshot here, it's not a thing to be excluded from emulator.

Comment: It is supposed to show up on a Settings page for the app, for apps that tend to consume a lot of battery. See [my May blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/05/24/android-o-background-limitations-not-just-targetsdkversion-o.html) for some background on this. However, I have not yet been able to reproduce this in production.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for clarifying. So developers should not consider that option. If you want apps running on O, abide by the background limits!!

Comment: It is safest to assume that your app might be subject to 8.0's background execution limits, even if your `targetSdkVersion` is below 26. In some cases, you still do not need to make any changes. For example, if you have a service that downloads a file, and you are sure that the service will be done in less than a minute, the background restrictions will not affect you.

Comment: @CommonsWare In that case, target any API, all have same effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting to ***enable the background restriction*** is available in **App Info** -> **Battery** screen.

**Not reproducible in emulator yet.**

The option is not available when you initially install the application (targeting below API 26) until the app does some background work.

So i was able to produce it by-

1. Targeting Application at API 25
2. Create A long running service (around 5 minutes)
3. Starting the service from onCreate of MainActivity
4. Send App to background(press back) and leave device on Battery(No power connected)

Within a few minutes, the option will be available to enable the restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use adb to enable/disable the background limitations.

> Android 7.0 (API level 24) introduces some additional Android Debug Bridge (ADB) commands that you can use to test app behavior with those background processes disabled:
>
> - To simulate conditions where implicit broadcasts and background services are unavailable, enter the following command:
>   `$ adb shell cmd appops set <package_name> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore`
> - To re-enable implicit broadcasts and background services, enter the following command:
>   `$ adb shell cmd appops set <package_name> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND allow`

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization#further-optimization

And you can also set your app to run in background:

`adb shell am make-uid-idle <package>`

Source: [Android Oreo Background Execution Limits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc)