# How to use adb to stop app from running in background?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm trying to make some apps on my phone to NOT run in the background. I tried from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707377/5884503:

```
lz@vm:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb shell cmd appops set package:com.whatsapp RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
Error: No UID for package:com.whatsapp in user 0
```

How can I make whatsapp (and others) to not run in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

cmd appops set <package_name> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore

in your case

adb shell cmd appops set com.whatsapp RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore

Answer (score 1):

You should run it like `./adb shell cmd appops set com.whatsapp RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore` i.e. without `package:`